# Predicting house prices with machine learning. Problem with time-varying variables

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, prediction, cross-section, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm currently trying to cross-sectionally predict house prices using statistical learning methods. I have collected prices from 2009 until 2020. I have loads of time-invariant variables on the individual houses such as distance to the sea, number of rooms, etc. It is, however, also known that macroeconomic factors affect prices, why I would like to include variables such as unemployment, where if the house is sold in, lets say, 2012 I then write the unemployment for that year.

I am having a hard time figuring out if this makes sense? This is first and foremost a cross-sectional study, so can I also include variables where the variation is in the time-series dimension?

Answer (score 0):

you might have to use temporal aggregates such as # of houses sold of a particular class PER MONTH/PERIOD and use economic indicators. The problem is economic indicators are usually reported on a quarterly basis or annual basis.  You  might have to make a decision regarding the appropriate "TIME BUCKET".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you maybe elaborate on your reply, as i'm not sure that I understand. I am able to collect economic variables on a quarterly basis. As my cross sectional collected data is spanning 11 years, I want to correct for macroeconomic fluctuations, as they affect house prices. My thought is that I can include these macroeconomic variables and just input the values of these macroeconomic variables for the year and quarter each house is sold. So if a house is sold in the third quarter of 2012, then I use the values of the macroeconomic values for the third quarter of 2012.